# Messaging between two processes

Tags: java, process

In my project, I should create a process via "Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec();". After that each of two processes(one is current one, which calls exec(), and other one that is created by exec()) should check if another process was closed. Current process can do this simply via "if (p.isAlive()) {action}" in endless loop. But if current process was closed, how could process "p" get information about it?
We could regulary send messages to inputstream of process by "p.getInputStream()" and after send messages to it... But how could we get this inputstream inside process "p"? I've tried do something like that: "Runtime.getRuntime().getLocalizedInputStream(someInputStream)", but it is deprecated...
So how could process "p" get information about current process closing?

Comment: Without much information on your context I would say that the parent process (the 1st one) should never finish (or be closed) before the child process (the 2nd one). Playing with input/output streams can lead to errors so be careful, search for **Interprocess communication** (IPC) for information on what can be done.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand you correctly, when you close a Process p, p != null right?

Comment: Superbob, why second process should be closed before first? As I understand when I call "Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec();" in Windows task manager we could see new javaw.exe process. So it is a separate process with it's memory. And they are independent.

Comment: Steven, yes, you're right. I just want second process to indicate closing first one.